# How to host mobile app backend with Google Cloud Platform?

Tags: nginx, google-cloud-platform, docker-compose, dockerfile, google-cloud-run

I’m getting ready to deploy my first app to the app store but I’m a bit confused with the process.

I have created a docker compose file for my Django REST backend which uses the Google API so I wanted to host it with Google Cloud Run, but after some research it seems like Cloud Run isn’t the best option for mobile apps? So I thought about using Google Kubernetes Engine.

From what I understand, after I make my docker compose file, I push it to a container registry then deploy it to Cloud Run/GKE?

docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3'

services:
  backend:
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: ./Dockerfile
    env_file:
      - ./backend/.env
    container_name: backend
    ports:
      - 8000:8000
  db:
    image: postgres:latest
    restart: always
    env_file:
      - ./backend/.env
    volumes:
      - ./postgres-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
  nginx:
    build:
      context: ./nginx
      dockerfile: ./Dockerfile
    container_name: nginx
    ports:
      - 80:80
    depends_on:
      - backend
```

My .env file:

```
GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=/path/to/file/creds.json
... other vars
```

Backend Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.9-slim

WORKDIR /app

ENV PYTHONNUNBUFFERED 1

RUN pip install --upgrade pip
COPY requirements.txt .
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt 

COPY . .

CMD ["python", "manage.py", "runserver", "0.0.0.0:8000"]
```

Nginx Dockerfile:

```
# Base image
FROM nginx:1.23.3-alpine

# Copy Nginx configuration
COPY nginx.conf ./nginx/nginx.conf

# Expose port
EXPOSE 80
```

Nginx.conf:

```
upstream backend {
  server backend:8000;
}

server {
  listen 80;

  location / {
    proxy_pass http://backend;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
  }
}
```

Looking for any advice that can lead me in the right direction and a better understanding with this process.

Thank you!

Comment: Docker compose is not the best place on Cloud Run. If you have a single container, Cloud Run is awesome. In fact, it's not a matter of mobile or web backend. If you want to serve API in serverless way and with a container, Cloud Run is the best place. Can you share your docker compose to let us know if you use Cloud Run anti pattern (or limits)?

Comment: I updated the question with my docker-compose. I also been having an issue when running docker-compose up. I get this error: FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/path/to/file/creds.json' even though the credentials file is there. Been stuck on this for days, would appreciate any advice.

Comment: You'll have to give us more info. What is this `creds.json` file for? It's path on your filesystem likely differs from its path inside your container. What Google APIs are you using? As Guillaume mentioned, Cloud Run isn't the best fit for multi-container apps at this time, but it and Cloud Functions (and App Engine) work great as mobile backends & likely require less effort.

Comment: ok... interesting. thanks. I am using the google secret manager to retrieve the Django secret key. If my app is somewhat similar to a social app, would cloud functions/ app engine still be good?

Comment: Since you're using Docker, is it possible to get your app in 1 container? If so, use Cloud Run. Cloud Functions is for single endpoint/functionality code (e.g., a function in the cloud). App Engine is older & is for deploy-from-source custom containers, so it's not right for you. I made a video to help you differentiate b/w the 3 serverless platforms: https://youtu.be/gle26fT28Bw . Instead of downloading/using a credentials file, see if you can use ADC (application default credentials). See https://cloud.google.com/secret-manager/docs/authentication#on-gcp

Comment: Firstly, you don't need a service account key file, either in your env var or in secret manager. Use Cloud Run runtime service account configuration to use the corrrect identity and permissions. Then, for now, with Cloud Run, if you have 2 container (NGINX and a backend) deploy 2 services and put a Load balancer in front of the 2 to have a single domain name (and so not have issues with CORS). It's a boring integration, but it's enterprise grade and each service will be able to scale independently

Comment: I’ve gone into the IAM section in the google console and gave the account correct permissions but would get error saying file/directory not found. 

Also, I’m nginx for reverse proxy and load balancer. Will I need to remove the load balancer from nginx?

Comment: I updated the qeustion with my nginx and backend docker files

Comment: I’m new to docker and google cloud. Learning as I go. I’m trying to remake this without using docker compose so I can just deploy a single image to cloud run. Any resources that can help me understand how to package all this in a single dockerfile? Everything I find says to use docker compose

Comment: Hi jdez... Your question is very broad, difficult to answer because of that. I figure out from it that you have a little or no knowledge of cloud-run or other cloud services. Friendly speaking, I would not approach to the cloud "learning as you go" since you can make very big mistakes and drain you credit card provided to your billing account. Just a friendly advice.